# command to compile typescript in react-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I went through this tutorial

https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript

However, I am using npm and the only command to compile typescript I see in that page is "yarn tsc"

I found another blog that said "npm start" does this but when I add this one line to my typescript, it still compiles and should not since I do not declare a variable something, nor a variable called blah ->

something = blah;

What command should I run to compile/type-check?  I am looking for it to fail because of the above line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `npx` to run things you don't have globally: `npx tsc`

Answer (score 0):

I think the TS compilation (transcompilation or transpiling to JS) happens when the JS bundle is generated when you run `npm start` or when you release your app.

If you just want to check types, syntax and lint you might want to run:

`eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx`

You can also do `tsc` only, and this will check typescript according to your tsconfig.json file. Please note you need to have typescript installed globally with `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: except npm start did not fail when I put in compile errors while npx tsc does (the other person's answer)